# tensorflow: ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'MatMul_1'

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I met with an error in the following code, when I'm trying to multiply a dense matrix with a sparse matrix.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
B = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)

IsFoc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
IsFoc_Diag = tf.diag(IsFoc)

IsUnFoc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
IsUnFoc_Diag = tf.diag(IsUnFoc)

b = tf.matmul(IsFoc_Diag,IsUnFoc_Diag)
a = tf.matmul(IsFoc_Diag,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
    a = tf.matmul(IsFoc_Diag,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1813, in matmul
    name=name)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 2245, in _sparse_mat_mul
    b_is_sparse=b_is_sparse, name=name)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/mypath.pfc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'SparseMatMul') with input shapes: [?,1,?,1], ?.
```

I know there are similar questions discussing similar errors, however, I cannot get the key reason for this type of error.

The error only happens to the line `a = tf.matmul(IsFoc_Diag,tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A),a_is_sparse=False,b_is_sparse=True)`. I hope someone could kindly answer my question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you print the shapes using `tensor.get_shape().as_list()` and then check both satisfies multiplicative properties?.